# BIND DNS Restrict Clients to certain domains

Tags: linux, bind

I am running a BIND DNS Server with 1 authoritative zone (abc.com) and 2 forwarded internal zones (rst.com and xyz.com). This server is also acting as a internet cache server.

My requirement is to restrict clients based on subnets to certain domains.

1. Subnet A (192.168.1.0/24) can only resolve the authoritative and forwarded internal zones and not internet.
2. Other subnets can resolve internet + plus forwarded zones but not the authoritative zone.

I have configured the following named.conf file and the 2nd rule is working fine but the first rule is not working for any domain. the server is running in chroot environment
Anyone see any mistake in the configuration please highlight

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        allow-query     { any; };
        allow-query-cache { any; };

        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation no;

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

        /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
        include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";

forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };
forward only;

};


view "internal" {
        match-clients { 192.168.1.100/32; };
        recursion yes;

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
zone "abc.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "abc.com";
};
zone "rst.com" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { 192.168.20.10; 192.168.20.20; };
};

zone "xyz.com" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { 192.168.10.10; 192.168.10.20; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
};

view "other" {
        match-clients { any; };

zone "." IN {
      type hint;
      file "named.ca";
};

zone "rst.com" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { 192.168.20.10; 192.168.20.20; };
};

zone "xyz.com" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { 192.168.10.10; 192.168.10.20; };
};
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
};
```

Comment: Views and response policy zones seem like what you're looking for.

Comment: I have update OP with my config file. can you please check what m I doing wrong

Comment: I was able to do the configuration correctly.. Thanks for the pointing me to the right feature.

Comment: Using the same server to be both authoritative and recursive is not a good idea and will yield problems. You should separate both services.

Comment: Actually the authoritative is used only for few clients with fake records.